# make differential in DATE query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, where-clause

what is the different from this mysql query:

```
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

and this

```
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

i have tried both but i cant see the different.

Comment: Careful... the first of these two won't be able to take advantage of any index you have created on your date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For today's CURRENT_DATE, i.e.: 23-September-2010:

`WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)` is `date` also in September, i.e. between 01-September and 30-September of any year.

`WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()` is `date` within the last 30/31 days. If we're on 23rd, this will give you an interval between 23-August-2010 and 23-September-2010.

Comment: the dates you gave for MONTH are slightly misleading - the year is not taken into account, hence _any_ september will match, not just 2010.

Answer (score 0):

The first one

```
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

will select rows where the month of the `date` column is the same as the current month (e.g. all rows for which the month of the `date` field is September.

The second one

```
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

will select rows for which the `date` field is between now and a month ago.